# What is the easiest way to compute the residue of $\frac{z e^{zt}}{(z^2+1)^3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

What is an easy way to compute the residue of the following complex function at $z=i$?

$$f(z)= \frac{z e^{zt}}{(z^2+1)^3}$$

I have tried to use the classic residue formula for an arbitrary order but it gives a tedious second derivative to be evaluated. I have also tried evaluating the residue by series expansion around $z=i$ but I am not sure exactly how to proceed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $z=i+u$ and insert
$$
\frac{(i+u)e^{it+tu}}{u^2(2i+u)^2}=\frac{(i+u)(-2i+u)^2e^{it+tu}}{u^2(4+u^2)^2}
$$
insert Taylor expansions in the numerator and expand. As you need the linear term, the first degree Taylor polynomials are sufficient.
$$
=e^{it}\frac{(i+u)(-4-4iu)(1+tu)+O(u^2)}{u^2·4^2}=e^{it}\frac{-i-itu+O(u^2)}{4u^2}
$$

Comment: I dont really see the simplification though

Comment: @johnmelon Isn't this *really*  much simpler, quicker and shorter than differentiate twice that function of yours? +1

Comment: Ok thanks ! Makes sense